# How to sort by n-th element of array in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a document like this:

```
{
    ...
    "times": ["9:00", "10:30", "12:30"]
    ...
}
```

Is it possible in Mongoose to find and sort results by n-th element of an array? Like:

```
{ sort: { 'times[0]': 1 } }
```

I've tried this approach but it doesn't work. I think Mongoose treats `times[0]` as a key, and my document doesn't have such a key. Mongoose doesn't consider it as reference to an array's element. This is my query:

```
Product.find({
    'type': type
}, null, {sort: {'times[0]': -1}}, function(err, data) {
    if(err) {
        console.error(err);
        db.close(disconnect);
    }
    console.log('data: ', data);
    db.close(disconnect);
})
```

Is it possible in Mongoose? Or I should sort results in JS after fetching?

Comment: Did you try sorting by `{ 'times.0': 1 }`?

Comment: @JohnnyHK, thank you. It works. It sorts results but not in terms of time. Because I store `times` as strings it sorts them as strings, I think.

Comment: Yep, that would make sense.